# Additional Information pop up box next to a variation in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I am creating a commerce site using Drupal Commerce, there are some variations for products that I would like to inform the customers about. Theres the option of having a sticker finish that is a variation and I wanted to have a "What is this?" text field right next to the select list that then launches a colorbox/fancybox/popup that displays additional information about that variation. Something similar to this:

[image: The Variation Box]
[image: The popup that follows when the question mark is clicked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised that there wasn't a module that did this so I've created one.

It is only a sandbox project at the moment as I'm still waiting to get approved to create full projects.

[Sandbox page](https://drupal.org/sandbox/dahousecat/2240445)

It can however be downloaded from [here](http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/dahousecat/2240445.git/snapshot/cbcb2b4b49b19d637edb4cd70ef08c530f9f52fd.tar.gz). You will then need to extract the .tar.gz to a .tar, and then extract that to a folder called "2240445-cbcb2b4" and then rename that folder to field_info_popup (Phew!).

I've tested it with all the core field types and seems to work fine but if you do find any bugs then they can be posted [here](https://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/2240445).

Comment: Wow thats awesome! Thank you so much! I will let you know if any bugs pop up